# Hypothetical symmetric carbon peroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, theoretical-chemistry, identification

Could a hypothetical carbon peroxide $\ce{C5O12}$ with the following structure ([MolView — 3D model](https://molview.org?smiles=C123C45OOC11OOC2(OO4)OOC3(OO5)OO1)) exist, and I what its properties would be (other than decomposing, of course)?

[image: C5O12 with a tetrahedral C5 core]

I tried looking it up myself, but I couldn't find any information on it or anything similar.

Comment: Huh, this thing could be perhaps an interesting oxidiser, if it didn't decompose outside of argon matrix ;)

Comment: Have a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxocarbon

Comment: I think the weakness here is the multiple C-O single bonds on each carbon. Those will eliminate readily in favor of C=O bonds, so I don't think this thing would even be metastable, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Complex/compact molecules are better presented with white background, fog showing depth, thinner bonds and smaller atomic radii. I used Jmol with `zshadepower=1`, `wireframe 0.075` and `spacefill 0.2` to produce a new static image to supplement the one that MolView generates. cc @Editors Please don't use lossy formats for images and don't apply compression to PNG images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your molecule basically consists of a bunch of [1,2-dioxolane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,2-Dioxolane) rings fused together.

Since 1,2-dioxolane exists, I would guess that your molecule probably does too, at least under suitable conditions (which might involve an ultra-cold [argon matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_isolation) in complete darkness). As noted in the comments below, though, the presence of multiple peroxide groups on each outer carbon might be enough to make it unstable even under ideal conditions, so take that with a grain of salt.

In any case, with all those fused peroxide rings packed tightly together, synthesizing it is going to be another matter. Still, enterprising chemists have managed to prepare some pretty crazy molecules, so if it's stable at all (however marginally), I wouldn't rule out the possibility that someone might some day create it.

Anyway, I expect that your molecule, like [organic peroxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_peroxides) in general, will be rather highly reactive. If heated, it will likely thermally decompose into smaller, more stable molecules such as $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ (and maybe $\ce{CO}$), as in: $$\ce{C5O12 -> 5 CO2 + O2}$$

This reaction is exothermic, and can thus [self-accelerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_accelerating_decomposition_temperature) if the sample is concentrated enough and not sufficiently well cooled, leading to runaway (and potentially even explosive) decomposition. Impurities that can react with the peroxide groups (which your molecule is entirely covered in!) are also likely to accelerate this decomposition.

In theory, *if* your molecule was stable enough to safely store and handle, it could make a pretty good explosive and/or a rocket propellant, either on its own or as an oxidizer combined with something less oxygen-rich as fuel in a bipropellant mix. That said, the world is full of compounds that *could* be great explosives or rocket fuels, if only they were stable enough — the real challenge in high-energy chemistry is not making a molecule that goes boom, it's making one that will *not* go boom until you want it to.

Comment: As noted in my comment above, the difference between this beast and 1,2 dioxolane is the multiple oxygens attached to each carbon, which I would expect to readily eliminate. They're not stable like acetals are because the alkyl peroxide leaving group here is much better than the alkoxide in an acetal.

Answer (score 7):

Carbon is not very good at forming stable peroxide compounds (prospective chemists are early and often warned about ethers turning into explosive peroxides), so this compound with multiple peroxide linkages is going to go boom.

But if we are careful to bond oxygen just to carbon, then a surprising variety of [oxocarbons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxocarbon) are known. Far beyond just the widely known carbon monoxide and carbon dioxide, they have a wide variety of structures and properties, including linear molecules, ring-based systems, and polymers. The linked WP article gives a good overview.

**Linear dioxides: an odd feature**

One of the most notable types of oxocarbons are linear dioxides. Most readers are aware of $\ce{CO2}$, but there can also be $\ce{C2O2}$, $\ce{C3O2}$, etc; chains as long as 21 carbon atoms are known.

Among these the most stable are $\ce{CO2}$ of course, $\ce{C3O2}$, and $\ce{C5O2}$ (the latter is stable in solution up to room temperature), whereas $\ce{C2O2}$ is highly unstable and $\ce{C4O2}$ can be kept only in the dark in a frozen argon matrix. Moreover, longer $\ce{C_nO2}$ are reported in the WP article only for odd values. What favors the odd-numbered members?

**"Linear aromaticity"? The revenge of 4n**

In these molecules all the atoms are $sp$ hybridized, so each atom contributes two $p$ orbitals to the delocalized pi system and all the pi orbitals are doubly degenerate. Thus a closed-shell electronic structure with increased stability due to pi-electron delocalization is favored by a $4n$ pi-electron count, not $4n+2$ as in the usual sort of aromaticity. With each carbon atom contributing two electrons to the pi orbitals and each oxygen contributing three, what might be called the "linear aromatic" structures are those with an odd number of carbon atoms, which are indeed the more stable and predominant ones.

**Peroxocarbon anions**

Although neutral oxocarbons with peroxide linkages are obtained only in extreme circumstances, both [peroxycarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxycarbonate) and [peroxydicarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxydicarbonate) ions are well-known and reasonably accessible.

Peroxycarbonate, $\ce{O^- - O - CO2^-}$, can be made by electrolyzing molten lithium carbonate or cold, concentrated aqueous lithium carbonate solution. It is known as such only in solution, but the protonated ion $\ce{HO - O - CO2^-}$ has been isolated as the potassium and rubidium salts [1-4]. Note the location of the protonic hydrogen; the terminal peroxy oxygen is more basic than the single oxygen atoms attached to carbon. The terminal peroxy oxygen is effectively cut off from the pi bonding in this ion, so its negative charge remains (formally) localized. In addition, the attached proton may be incorporated into a five-membered hydrogen-bonded ring (cf. [this discussion of Caro's Acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133835/17175)).

Peroxydicarbonate, $\ce{CO2^- - O - O - CO2^-}$, is made by electrolysis of molten lithium carbonate or by electrolyzing a saturated aqueous solution of rubidium carbonate. This ion is stable enough for its potassium and rubidium salts to have been isolated (with no protonation of the ion)[5-7]. The light blue potassium salt decomposes with loss of oxygen and carbon dioxide, but only slowly below 141°C[6].

**References**

1.
Mimoza Gjikaj (2001), "Darstellung und strukturelle Charakterisierung neuer Alkali- bzw. Erdalkalimetallperoxide, -hydrogenperoxide, -peroxocarbonate und -peroxohydrate" Archived 2012-02-25 at the Wayback Machine. Doctoral Thesis, University of Köln. 115 pages.

2.
Adam, Arnold; Mehta, Mathias (1998). "KH(O2)CO2·H2O2—An Oxygen-Rich Salt of Monoperoxocarbonic Acid". *Angewandte Chemie International Edition*. **37** (10): 1387–1388. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1521-3773(19980605)37:10<1387::AID-ANIE1387>3.0.CO;2-3. ISSN 1521-3773. PMID 29710903.

3.
M. Mehta and A. Adam (1998), *Z. Kristallogr., Suppl.* Issue 15 p. 53. Cited by Gjikaj.

4.
M. Mehta and A. Adam (1998), *Z. Kristallogr., Suppl.* Issue 15 p. 46. Cited by Gjikaj.

5.
Constam, E. J.; von Hansen, A. (1896). "Elektrolytische Darstellung einer neuen Klasse oxidierender Substanzen". *Zeitschrift für Elektrochemie*. **7**: 18 ff. https://doi.org/10.1002/bbpc.189600032 (inactive 31 October 2021).

6.
Dinnebier, Robert E.; Vensky, Sascha; Stephens, Peter W.; Jansen, Martin (2002). "Crystal Structure of K2[C2O6]". Angewandte Chemie International Edition. 41 (11): 1922–1924. https://doi.org/10.1002/1521-3773(20020603)41:11<1922::AID-ANIE1922>3.0.CO;2-T.

7.
Dinnebier, Robert E.; Vensky, Sascha; Jansen, Martin (2003). "Crystal and Molecular Structure of Rubidium Peroxodicarbonate Rb2[C2O6]". *Chemistry: A European Journal*. **9** (18): 4391–4395. https://doi.org/10.1002/chem.200304914. PMID 14502625.

Comment: Cool, but what about *peroxides*?

Comment: @mithoron there's the rub, unfortunately. The oxocarbons seen in the referenced article do not seem to include peroxides ... yet.

Comment: The best I could do was discuss a couple anions with a peroxide linkage.